# Как ускорить выполнение решения задачи "Встречалось ли число раньше"

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Вводится список чисел. Все числа списка находятся на одной строке.
>   Во входной строке записана последовательность чисел через пробел. Для каждого числа выведите слово YES (в отдельной строке), если это число ранее встречалось в последовательности или NO, если не встречалось.

Я сделала так:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
newset = ()
for i in a:
    print('YES') if i in newset else print('NO')
    newset = list(set(newset) | {i})
```

Проверяющая система утверждает, что можно сократить время работы кода. Что я не учла?

Comment: Думаю, синтаксис можно упростить: `newset = set()` и после `newset |= {i}`. Да и зачем вам тот сложный код присванивания? Можно просто: `newset.add(i)` (перед циклом `newset = set()`)

Comment: @gil9red да, помогло! )

Comment: еще один вариант: `seen = set(); print('\n'.join([f'{x}: NO' if x not in seen and not seen.add(x) else f'{x}: YES' for x in a]))`

Comment: @MaxU Вот это ничего себе!) не встречала такой подход f'...'  Спасибо!

Comment: @Lazarevna, это [новый (начиная с Python 3.6) стиль форматирования строк](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю такой рефакторинг:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
newset = set()
for i in a:
    print('YES' if i in newset else 'NO')
    newset.add(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Альтернативный вариант:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
seen = set()
print('\n'.join('NO' if x not in seen and not seen.add(x) else 'YES' for x in a))
```

Comment: Интересное решение с включенным в генератор множество :) Квадратные скобки в `join` не нужны )

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо! :)